# Beginner's book for Program Monitoring and Evaluation

Tags: progress-monitor, evaluation

I am looking for a basic book for 'Program Monitoring and Evaluation'. I searched the internet and could find the UNDP reports. But they are too comprehensive. Can anyone point me to some basic books to start off with?

Comment: We try to avoid Questions with no canonical Answer. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ for more details.

Comment: I have to attend an interview but no idea of 'Program Monitoring and Evaluation'. Hence I am asking this question. I hope people will pitch in with their answers. I just need a basic book to understand how these 2 things are done.

Comment: One of the first Google links is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitoring_and_evaluation which explains it very simply.

Comment: Yes.. I had gone through it and it gave me the links to th  various UN documentations. But these seem to be very comprehensive. Hence I was looking for some beginner's level text books.

Comment: If I got it right... a Wiki article is too comprehensive, and you expect a whole book to be less comprehensive? It's a bit unusual, IMHO.

Comment: @Tiago : I meant the UN documentations through the wiki article were comprehensive for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. There's [this](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=nqpiCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1&dq='Program%20Monitoring%20and%20Evaluation'%20book&pg=PT19#v=onepage&q='Program%20Monitoring%20and%20Evaluation'%20book&f=false) eBook available on Google books. [image]
2. There's [this](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=ES7nUJbaCOsC&lpg=PP1&dq='Program%20Monitoring%20and%20Evaluation'%20book&pg=PR9#v=onepage&q='Program%20Monitoring%20and%20Evaluation'%20book&f=false) book which is unrelated to computers that you can buy and preview on Google books. [image]
3. [Here's](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=qcaf6J65a_8C&lpg=PP1&dq='Program%20Monitoring%20and%20Evaluation'%20book&pg=PR4#v=onepage&q='Program%20Monitoring%20and%20Evaluation'%20book&f=false) another book you can buy and preview on Google books. [image]
4. Here's a [60 page PDF](https://www.geog.ox.ac.uk/research/technologies/projects/mesc/guide-to-monitoring-and-evaluation-v1-march2014.pdf) you can download on the subject.
5. [Here's](https://www.bookdepository.com/Program-Evaluation-Third-Edition-John-M.-Owen/9781593854065) a book you can buy on the subject. [image]
6. [Here's](https://www.ebooks.com/2015000/developing-monitoring-and-evaluation-frameworks/patrick-ian-markiewicz-anne) an eBook on the subject. [image]